# Android SDK takes a huge amount of disk space

Tags: android, sdk

I did many searches on the web, and only partially I understood what I have to do.

When my IDE (Android Studio) reminded me that are available recent update for android SDK, I provided to install them. Now I notice that the Android-SDK directory occupies 87Gb of HDD memory.
This because are installed all the Android API from older version to the latest new.

Today I decided to delete all the SDK directory and perform a clean installaton of the SDK tool.
What I ask is which are the minimum things that I've to install from the SDK manager to be up and running for Android Development.
Consider that my apps must run from Android API 14 (4.0 IceCream) to the least available API version (currently on October 2017 is API 25).
In addiction I use an Android Emulator with Lollipop 5.1 (API 22).

The last thing I ask is when there is a new available and I would to install it, should I unistall all the older API version to prevent SDK grow up?

This is the screenshot of my Android Studio SKD manager.
As you can see the only checked API is 7.1.1 Nougat API 25.
[image]

This is a series of screenshot of package details of SDK Manager
[image]
[image]

[image]

The others are all unchecked.
I have to say that for Android 5.1 Lollipop API 22, check marks appear after I create the Android Emulator with Lollipop Installed.

NB: I need only things for mobile programming, not TV or Wearable.

Comment: I recommend that you see exactly what in your Android SDK directory is taking up the space. For example, on Linux, you might run `du -d 1 -m` to see the amount of disk space used by the top-level SDK directories. In my case, ~80GB is in `system-images`, and that is where the emulator images reside. If yours is the same, uninstall any emulator images that you are not going to be using.

Comment: The problem is that every time that IDE suggested me to install SDK updates I installed them and so I accumulated all the API (with System Image, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should I unistall all the older API version to prevent SDK grow up?

Yes you can do this to reduce the space size taken by the SDK

Cons : you will not be able to use [`instant run`](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html) if you are running your app on particular device on lollipop and above.

Note : you can drop old version under API 14 as support library has also dropped the support for older version

[`From docs, Revision 26.0.0 Release (July 2017)`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)

> The minimum SDK version has been increased to 14. As a result, many
>   APIs that existed only for compatibility with pre-14 API levels have
>   been deprecated. Clients of these APIs should migrate to their
>   framework equivalents as noted in the reference page for each
>   deprecated API.

Comment: For example if in the build.gradle file of the app, I write these lines:         `minSdkVersion 21`
`targetSdkVersion 25` Will I am able to run my app on device that have API in this range even if in SDK Manager I didn't install API 21 or above?

Comment: which lines ? though you just add dependencies in gradle for as per your target API , min support (which not reuired the API in SDK unless you want to run you ap on that API), support library versions , 3rd party etc so after removing you app will be able to run on other API's but you can test it on emulator

Comment: Not in emulator, but on physical device. Now I've only API 22 (because emulator require that, it's a my choose) and API 25 (the latest, exluding Android O). If a build my app, will it able to run on a physical phone that run Android 5.0 (API 21) or 6.0 (API 23) even if in my sdk manager I didn't install these API?

Comment: Ok, you read in my mind,  you answer prior that I wrote the question.