# minSdkVersion cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1 Manifest Merger Failed

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to import a project downloaded into my Android SDK app, But am getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1] C:\Users\ambil\AndroidStudioProjects\Datewithme1\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\26.0.0-alpha1\AndroidManifest.xml
Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v4" to force usage
```

What should I do ?

Comment: proceed according to this `uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library`

Comment: @VivekMishra terrible idea. Doing that will crash the library because it can use APIs that require min API 14+. Incrementing minSDK to at least 14 in the project is the way to go, but this is a duplicate (looking for the post) so it doesn't really matter

Comment: Duplicate of [Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438170/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-14)

Comment: @Zoe I never said to change that in library. I posted that to give a direction for search.

Comment: @VivekMishra that's not what I said either. You said proceed according to the warning, which imples: `Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v4" to force usage` - that is a terrible idea. It will lead to crashes in that big API gaps (between current minSDK and library minSDK) related to the library using newer APIs that aren't added in API 8, and there's no backwards compatibility either (because then minSDK would be 8 not 14)

Comment: @Zoe not exactly a dupe , sooner or later we all have to drop API lower than 14, why read my answer below , same reason i mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46668081/android-sdk-takes-a-huge-amount-of-disk-space/46668600#46668600) but both questions are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is clear: `uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library`

Please simple upgrade your `minSdkVersion` to level 14 - Android 4.0 ( ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH ) and refresh gradle to update changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to the reason

[`support library has also dropped the support for older version less than 14`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0)

> The minimum SDK version has been increased to 14. As a result, many
>   APIs that existed only for compatibility with pre-14 API levels have
>   been deprecated. Clients of these APIs should migrate to their
>   framework equivalents as noted in the reference page for each
>   deprecated API

So the optimal solution is to use minsdk 14 otherwise you can add

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v4"/>
```

or you can try using the support lib versions below 26.0.0

Note : Using latest support lib versions with API below 14 can also cause crashes and unexpected behaviors and will not be able to use newer API's in support lib for obvious reasons.